# Почему элемент выводится только для одной строки?

Tags: fortran

Задание такое: на каждой строке матрицы вывести минимальный элемент. У меня выводит только для одной строки, а должен - для каждой.

```
program m23
integer::n,x,y,m,min
integer,allocatable,dimension(:,:)::a
print*,'Enter M'
read*,m
print*,'Enter N'
read*,n
allocate(a(m,n))
print*,'Enter elements of matrix'
do y=1,m
    read*,(a(y,x),x=1,n)
end do
do x=1,n
    min=a(1,x)
    do y=1,m
        if(a(y,x)<min)then
            min=a(y,x)
        end if
    end do
    print*,'Min na',x
end do
do y=1,m
    print*,'Stroke',min
end do
deallocate(a)
end program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если тебе нужно вывести минимумы для каждой строки(), то надо было написать так.

```
integer,allocatable,dimension()::min;
...
allocate(min(n));
do x=1,n
    min(x)=a(1,x)
    do y=1,m
        if(a(y,x)<min(x))then
            min(x)=a(y,x)
        end if
    end do
end do
do x=1,n
    print*,'Min na',x
    print*,'Stroke',min(x)
end do
deallocate(min)
```

Comment: Как видно надо было объявить min как массив и заносить минимумы уже туда.

Comment: Спасибо, Арман! Задачу сдал! Там в циклах проблемы были. Я смотрю вы понимаете фортран, вы не против, если буду иногда обращатся к вам?

Comment: Я понимаю фортран только на простейшем алгоритмическом уровне. Когда-то давно читал книгу по фортрану 90.

Comment: Жаль не многие его понимают.
Мне нужно только исправление ошибок в коде не более.)